# What native GUI applications can easily make a photo collage grid?

Tags: software-recommendation, photo-management, photo

Despite being an Ubuntu user for many years, for several years I have been using [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) on Windows to make photo collage grids of my photos.

The process for doing this is to select either a folder of photos or a number of photos and press the "Create Collage" button. The photos are usually arranged by date taken (which I prefer), but this can be changed by manually rearranging them. The results look like this:

[image: Example collage]

*[Click here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/hellocatfood/8348075290/in/photostream) for a bigger version*

Is there native software - i.e. doesn't require Wine or run in a browser - with a GUI (for easy editing) available for Ubuntu that can make collages in the same way?

Comment: I'd argue that it isn't as I'm asking for a specific type of collage, which neither of the programs mentioned in the answers to that question can actually produce

Comment: Yes, on further thought you are correct-I'm interested in the question too and have found out that those programs mentioned in the other question don't do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [GIMP Plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/)

There are some plugins for [GIMP](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp) [image: Install gimp] available which should do the job.

Personally I only have experience with the [Image Grid Layout](http://registry.gimp.org/node/2236) plugin which merges several images into one based on a predefined grid layout. As an alternative you may try [Index Print](http://registry.gimp.org/node/24503) which also allows sorting by date.

Comment: Image Grid Layout does the job, though I imagine it'd run slowly with several hundred images open. Do you have installation instructions for Index Print? The ones on the website are vague.

Comment: sorry no, I did not try Index Print - too vague ;)